# Is it possible to save the response data from a Fetch to a variable to use later?

Tags: javascript, fetch

Using the Fetch API I'm making a `GET` request to an API endpoint which returns an object. **I would like to save this object to use later, outside of the Fetch, but it seems that when I do, the variable I've initialized returns `undefined`.**

I have initialized a variable before the fetch which I set equal to the response data inside a `.then` call:

```
const getObject = (convoId) => {
  let url = base_url + `/${convoId}`
  let convo;    //<-- initializing the variable

  fetch(url, { method: "GET", headers })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => convo = data)
  .then(() => console.log(convo)) //<-- successfully logs the data
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });

  console.log(convo);     //<-- logs undefined
};
```

Because I initialized `convo` before the fetch and assigned it the value of the data object from the response, I expected that `convo` would be assigned  - especially because logging `convo` within the `.then` call was successful.

But it appears it is only valid inside the fetch. I'm probably overlooking something small, so any helpful feedback is very welcome!

Comment: I am still new to javascript and I know this is old and I am sure you found your solution, but for others who are looking, this call is async, so the data is probably coming after you already console out the convo var